# Почему функция становится анонимной

Tags: javascript

Почему функция обернутая событием становится анонимной?

Например:

В первом случае `console.log(myFunction())` выдает `not defined`:

```
    document.getElementById("form").on('submit', function myFunction() {

    ...

    });
```

Во втором случае `console.log(myFunction())` выдает значение `myFunction()`:

```
    document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", myFunction);

    function myFunction() {

    ...

    }
```

Мне не понятно почему так происходит, событие тоже является как бы переменной?И если мы оборачиваем что-то в него это исключает функцию из области видимости? Объясните пожалуйста

Comment: Непонятно что вам непонятно, в первом случае вы передаёте анонимную функцию в качестве параметра и никакую переменную myFunction вы не создаёте, а во втором случае создаёте. И событие тут ни при чём

Comment: Простите, что не по теме — но мне больше интересно, отчего у вас "становится" с мягким знаком, а "является" — без.

Comment: Даже если вместо addEventListener напишете какой-нибудь setTimeout, результат будет аналогичный

Comment: @IgorR. Скорее всего я из деревни

Comment: Ну и во втором случае достаточно завернуть функцию в скобки, чтобы функция стала анонимной и всё сломалось

Comment: @andreymal Я понимаю,что если ее завернуть в скобки , то она станет анонимной. Я не понял почему это происходит

Comment: Потому что так придумали разработчики языка javascript ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Вообще, если объявить функцию без ничего (как во втором случае), то это получается Function Declaration и полноценная именованная функция, а если внутри какого-то выражения (в тех же скобках или в аргументах вызова какой-то функции), то это получается Function Expression, и дальнейшая судьба этой функции зависит от того, где используется это выражение

Comment: _становится анонимной_ - не совсем точная формулировка, она просто создается в другой области видимости. Этот как пытаться получить доступ к функции `b` снаружи функции `a`. [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/u9b0yp3o/).

Comment: По моему все очень даже логично.

Comment: Ну и судя по _событие тоже является как бы переменной_ - вы похоже не до конца разобрались что такое `addEventListener`. Так вот, это самая обычная функция, которая принимает параметр - строку и параметр - функцию.[пример](https://jsfiddle.net/nzg493fq/)

Comment: почему тут все пишут про анонимные функции, если в обоих примерах функции вполне себе именованные???